# Unix symbol \!* in alias cd 'chdir \!* && set prompt="${cwd} >"'

Tags: shell, unix, alias, csh

I'm unable to understand use of symbol `\!*` in the following alias statement
`alias cd 'chdir \!* && set prompt="${cwd} >"'`. This is related to csh

Comment: Not really a programming question - try http://unix.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: This looks like `csh`, the use of which is broadly discouraged. Either way, you should [edit] your question to add the appropriate tag ([tag:csh]? [tag:tcsh]?) and fix the inconsistency in the question (apparently `/$*` is just a typo? If not, explain how it relates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alias defines a command. This command can be launched with arguments, so the pattern `!*` represents the arguments that will be passed to the alias. For the definition to be correct, the symbol `!` is de-specialized with `\!` to prevent the replacement to operate during the alias definition but during the alias usage.

If you call it with `cd a b c d`, this would be like you type `chdir a b d c d && set prompt="${cwd} >"`